# #ifdef to detect arm64 build at compile time on iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa

When building an iOS project for arm64, how can one determine the build target is arm64 at compile time?

Comment: I figured there was a dupe but couldn't find it.  +1 to the OP since he can't be faulted for this.